# How to add user to Index Elasticsearch only if one dosen't exist before updating

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch , the problem I'm having is sometime the users don't get added to the index , not sure why, only happens sometimes.

1.My set up is when you register to my site a user gets added to the index
2.when a user updates thier profile , the index gets updated with their new info

3.When a user goes to update or edit thier profile, if they weren't added to the index , a error gets thrown.

I want to be able to add them to the index if they aren't added already when they update, in other words if there not already added to the index, then add them before updating

this is how I'm updating

```
$client = Clientbuilder::create()->build();
    $response = $client->update([
        'index' => 'users',
        'type' => 'user',
        'id' => Auth::user()->id,
        'body' => [
            'doc' => [
                $field => $data,
            ],
        ],

    ]);
}
```

then

```
if ($request->has('name')) {
        $user->name = strip_tags($request->input('name'));
        $user->save();

        //update elasticsearch users index
        $user->elasticupdate('name',$user->name);

    }
```

I'm added them to index like so

```
$client = Clientbuilder::create()->build();
        $response = $client->index([
            'index' => 'users',
            'type' => 'user',
            'id' => $user->id,
            'body' => [
                'username' => $user->username,
                'name' => $user->name,
                'profession' =>$user->getProfession(),
                'secondary_profession' =>$user->getSecondaryProfession(),
                'genre' => $user->getUserGenre(),
                'subgenre' => $user->getUserSubGenre(),
                'city' => $user->getCity(),
                'profilepic' => 'n026qso2xxztaphbwwey.png', //Default pics
                'backgroundpic' => 'backgrounddefaultpms_oa9mee.png', //Default pics
                // 'profilepic' => $user->getProfilePic(),
                // 'backbroundpic' => $user->getBackroundPic(),
                'country' => $user->country,
                'country_fips_code' => $user->country_fips_code,
                'state' => $user->getState(),
                //'affiliations' => $user->getAffiliations(),
                'affiliation_one' => ' ',
                'affiliation_two' => ' ',
                'affiliation_three' => ' ',
                'affiliation_four' => ' ',
                'affiliation_five' => ' ',
                'credential_one' => ' ',
                'credential_two' => ' ',
                'credential_three' => ' ',
                'credential_four' => ' ',
                'credential_five' => ' ',
                // 'countryAbr' => $countryAbr,
                // 'stateAbr' => $stateAbr,
                'cityGeonameId' => $user->geoname_id,
                'latlong' => [$origin],
            ],

        ]);
```

I thought about just running this everything they update their profile, but what if some of those fields that i have set as defaults are filled with actual data, example if a user was actually added to the index already and everything worked, then this would be overwriting it, any ideas

Answer (score 0):

You should set `op_type` field to `create` value like this:

```
$client = Clientbuilder::create()->build();
$response = $client->index([
    'index' => 'users',
    'type' => 'user',
    'id' => $user->id,
    'op_type' => 'create',
    'body' => [
        'username' => $user->username,
        'name' => $user->name,
        'profession' =>$user->getProfession(),
        'secondary_profession' =>$user->getSecondaryProfession(),
        'genre' => $user->getUserGenre(),
        'subgenre' => $user->getUserSubGenre(),
        'city' => $user->getCity(),
        'profilepic' => 'n026qso2xxztaphbwwey.png', //Default pics
        'backgroundpic' => 'backgrounddefaultpms_oa9mee.png', //Default pics
        // 'profilepic' => $user->getProfilePic(),
        // 'backbroundpic' => $user->getBackroundPic(),
        'country' => $user->country,
        'country_fips_code' => $user->country_fips_code,
        'state' => $user->getState(),
        //'affiliations' => $user->getAffiliations(),
        'affiliation_one' => ' ',
        'affiliation_two' => ' ',
        'affiliation_three' => ' ',
        'affiliation_four' => ' ',
        'affiliation_five' => ' ',
        'credential_one' => ' ',
        'credential_two' => ' ',
        'credential_three' => ' ',
        'credential_four' => ' ',
        'credential_five' => ' ',
        // 'countryAbr' => $countryAbr,
        // 'stateAbr' => $stateAbr,
        'cityGeonameId' => $user->geoname_id,
        'latlong' => [$origin],
    ],

]);
```

In this case, if user with the same id already exist, request will return an error, and you won't override an existing one. Take look at "Versioning" section here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html

Comment: This almost gets the job done, but the error it trows is what messes it up, how can i make it so that if id already exists, it just continues to the next line of code instead of throwing an error

Comment: You should just handle an error or skip it. It should not be a problem